# terraform running ansible on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have Terraform trying that is trying to run Ansible when creating an ec2 instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "jenkins-master" {
  depends_on = [aws_main_route_table_association.set-master-default-rt-assoc, aws_kms_alias.master_ebs_cmk]
  provider                    = aws.region-master
  ami                         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.linuxAmi.value
  instance_type               = var.instance-type
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.master-key.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.jenkins-sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.master_subnet_1.id
  ipv6_address_count          = 1

  root_block_device {
      encrypted = false
      volume_size = 30
   }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = <<EOF
      aws --profile myprofile ec2 wait instance-status-ok --region us-east-1 --instance-ids ${self.id} \
     && ansible-playbook --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_${self.tags.Name}' ansible_templates/install_jenkins.yaml
    EOF
   }
}
```

My terraform works  if I export the key id and secret of "myprofile"  as environmental variables

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

If I do not export "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" I get the following error

```
....
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "aws --profile myprofile ec2 wait instance-status-ok --region us-east-1 --instance-ids i-04db214244937ed60 \\\n&& ansible-playbook --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_jenkins_master_tf' ansible_templates/install_jenkins.yaml\n"]
....
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/pcooke/workspace/learn-
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): terraform/modules/ansible_templates/inventory_aws/tf_aws_ec2.yml with auto
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): plugin: Insufficient boto credentials found. Please provide them in your
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): inventory configuration file or set them as environment variables.
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/pcooke/workspace/learn-
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): terraform/modules/ansible_templates/inventory_aws/tf_aws_ec2.yml with yaml
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/pcooke/workspace/learn-
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): terraform/modules/ansible_templates/inventory_aws/tf_aws_ec2.yml with ini
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): plugin: Invalid host pattern '---' supplied, '---' is normally a sign this is a
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): YAML file.
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/pcooke/workspace/learn-
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): terraform/modules/ansible_templates/inventory_aws/tf_aws_ec2.yml as an
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): inventory source
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:
aws_instance.jenkins-master (local-exec): tag_Name_jenkins_master_tf
```

Is there a simple way to pass the AWS profile to Ansible so that Ansible can get the right key id and secret????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to pass the AWS profile to Ansible so that Ansible can get the right key id and secret?

As what user is Ansible executing the task?

You should include the key id and secret in a config file on the system under that user:

```sh
$ cat /home/myuser/.aws/config
[default] 
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...
region=...
output=...
```

This way, Ansible should read the key content from the system.

Another solution would be to add environment variables to the task:

```yaml
- hosts: local_test
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    env_vars:
      aws_access_key_id: abc
      aws_secret_key: abc
  tasks:
    - name: Terraform stuff
      shell: env
      environment: "{{ env_vars }}"
      register: my_env

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_env }}"
```

Note that describing secrets in a playbook isn't considered safe. In order to do that safely one can use [Ansible-vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html).

Comment: adding the key values here is definitively forbidden.  I will look at vault.  
I have many accounts and many users that deploy.   Setting the "default" key id and secret is not really viable.